# jquery update hidden field dependant on checkbox

Tags: jquery, function, input, field, hidden

I am currenlty using this to see if each rows check box in a specified table is checked.

```
$("#table_pdf_view input[type=checkbox][checked]").each(

    function() {



    }

 );
```

If the row is checked I want it to use the checkboxes input id to update a seperate hidden table.

```
echo '<td width="200px"><input type=" checkbox" id="'.$row['client_id'].'" name="download"></td>'.PHP_EOL;
```

The hidden table will contain one input field. If multiple rows are checked I would like to separate each id by a comma.

​

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do something like

```
var $checkboxes = $("#table_pdf_view input[type=checkbox]");
$checkboxes.on('change',function(){
   var ids = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').map(function(){
      return this.id; 
   }).get().join(',');
   $('#Hidden_input_id').val(ids);
});
```

Change `#Hidden_input_id` with the ID of your hidden input. This will update `hidden input's value` when users `check/uncheck` a checkbox.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/npmB3/1/

Read more on [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) and [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly until you specify the boundary for the checkboxes http://jsfiddle.net/npmB3/8/

Comment: @SamCorbet, thats because your markup is not valid and browser's correct the markup, like `chrome` takes the checkboxes out of table and the `selector` returns empty set. You have to put the checkboxes inside `td`. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/npmB3/13/

Comment: Thank you, for some reason I cant get it to work on my actual page but I'm sure it wont be too hard to figure out why. many thanks :)